# Adding a reference from a xproj to a csproj

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-4.6.1

I have a **".net 4.6.1" (A)** project and a **".net core 1.5" (B)** project.

I want add a reference to **"project_B_core_1.5"** in my **"project_A_net461"**.

At the beginning I got:

> A reference could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced.

Then I tried to add "net461" to "frameworks" in the core project (*). I Tried to add it again to **"project_A_net461"**, and this time there was no error.

The problem is that I can't access the namespace:

> The type or namespace 'name_of_B_project' does note exist in the namespace 'name_of_A_project' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It complains at `using name_of_B_project;`.

---

(*) Like this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {},
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've find more info about it (with possible solutions) here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/89

Comment: At least the suggested workaround works: 1) Remove reference to library project, 2) Add reference to compiled library DLL for .NET4XX