# How to build .xproj before .csproj

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41721131/831138).

As I'm not able to directly reference my .xproj in my .csproj in Visual Studio, I am forced to directly reference the built net461 dll. So in this situation, I want my .csproj to pre-compile the .xproj before running the .csproj itself.

I've tried modifying the .csproj manually and adding:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeFolder\SomeProject.xproj">
      <Project>{1A94B405-2D01-4A09-90D5-A5B31180A03B}</Project>
      <Name>SomeProjectNamespace</Name>
   </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

But when I build the .csproj, it doesn't build the .xproj.

I won't be able to debug .xproj when I run my .csproj, which is bad enough... but at least when I run the .csproj I want to be sure I have the last version of my .xproj compiled.

Comment: Not a solution but a slightly different approach. Are both projects big enough to keep them as .NET and .NET Core separately? I.e. why not unify them?

Comment: @Ignas I will do that at some point in the future... but it is referenced in 4 other projects that are quite large. One of them is a Windows Form project (yup...). I had to build an .net core API, and I wanted to at least share the same repository system (which I ported to .NET core, which was easy).

Answer (score 1):

xproj <=> csproj references in Visual Studio 2015 were always buggy and never worked well. As far as I know, there are no good workarounds.

That said, Visual Studio 2017 RC added support for building .NET Core and .NET Standard with csproj. This deprecates xproj and project.json.

With this new format, a project to project reference would look like this:

```
<!-- App.csproj -->
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Library\Library.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

<!-- Library.csproj -->
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```